# GGIR: Warning in recalibration

Tags: r

I am new in using GGIR and I would like your help. After g.part1 I am receiving the following warning: "Recalibration not done because not enough data in the file or because file is corrupt". The only output I am getting is an R.data format file and the g.part2 is not running.
Could that mean the files are actually corrupted?

Thank you for your help in advance.